# Procedure Advice

Tags: sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014, query-performance

I'm looking to boost performance on one of our processes within a production database. We have 2 sets of SPs which are by configuration settings stored within a configuration table.

An example syntax would be:

```
Declare @SWITCH BIT

IF @SWITCH = 1
INSERT INTO DEST_TABLE_A 
SELECT VALUES
  FROM SOURCE_TABLE

IF @SWITCH = 2
INSERT INTO DEST_TABLE_B
SELECT VALUES
  FROM SOURCE_TABLE
```

Would it be better practice in this instance to move the IF logic into the WHERE clause to create a standardized instead of the logic having a conditional within it?

E.g.

```
INSERT INTO DEST_TABLE_A
SELECT VALUES 
FROM SOURCE_TABLE
WHERE @SWITCH = 1

INSERT INTO DEST_TABLE_B
SELECT VALUES
FROM SOURCE_TABLE
WHERE @SWITCH = 2
```

I appreciate this might be an opinion piece but I was curious to see if anyone else has had experience with this scenario.

Comment: IMO, the IF statements (I would of written it as IF/ELSE) will be better because then it will only be 1 `INSERT INTO` call being made while your 2nd example will do 2 `INSERT INTO` calls, even if nothing gets inserted. It also doesn't make sense to me to write it out like the 2nd example since `@SWITCH` can only be set to 1 value at a time, so only one of the insert statements will actually be used.

Answer (score 0):

The second example might lead you to   [parameter sniffing problem](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/turgays/archive/2013/09/10/parameter-sniffing-problem-and-workarounds.aspx) . ([longer explanation here](https://sqlbits.com/Sessions/Event8/Parameter_Sniffing_Problem_in_SQL_Server_Stored_Procedures))

This issue is created by the query optimizer that generates an execution plan optimized for one of the values of the switch statement (and this is the value that you send first time when you call the stored procedure).

In your case, if you call the stored procedure with @switch = 1 first time, an execution plan for this parameter is generated. Subsequent calls with @switch = 2 might take significantlty longer times to process.